# promise execution error nodejs javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to node js. I am using `express` framework with `sequelize` orm to connect with my `mysql` database

Here's the one of the API Call I wrote

```
1    expressApp.post('/api/account_lister', (req, res) => {
2        var temp_obj = {}
3        var temp_list = []
4        WAAccount.findAll({where:{user_id:1}})
5            .then((DBData) => {
6            if ( DBData!== null ){
7                for (var i = 0; i < DBData.length; i++) {
8                    let wa_account_name = DBData[i].dataValues.wa_account_name
9                    let wa_id = DBData[i].dataValues.wa_id
10                   WAProperties.findAll({where:{wa_id:wa_id}})
11                        .then((DBData) => {
12                        if ( DBData!== null){
13                            for (var i = 0; i < DBData.length; i++) {
14                                temp_list.push(DBData[i].dataValues.wa_property_name)
15                            }
16                            temp_obj[wa_account_name] = temp_list
17                            temp_list = []
18                            console.log(temp_obj)  
19                        }
20                    })
21                    }
22            }
23        })
24        console.log(temp_obj)   
25        res.json({ success: true, account_property_list: temp_obj }); return;
26    })
```

In the Above Code, `WAAccount` and `WAProperties` are the two tables in `MySQL`. 
In the above code, there is two `then` function. the function in the `then` is executed in `async` manner. So the variable `temp_obj` in `line 24` returns empty. But in `line 18`, the `temp_obj` has values that were executed after `line 24` due to it is inside in `then` function. I want the `24th line` to be executed after the complete execution of `then` functions. how to make it. Help me with some solutions.

Comment: Move `res.json` inside `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
expressApp.post('/api/account_lister', async (req, res) => {
    var temp_obj = {}
    var temp_list = []
    const DBData = await WAAccount.findAll({where:{user_id:1}})   
    if ( DBData!== null ){
        for (var i = 0; i < DBData.length; i++) {
            let wa_account_name = DBData[i].dataValues.wa_account_name
            let wa_id = DBData[i].dataValues.wa_id
            const DBData2 = await WAProperties.findAll({where:{wa_id:wa_id}})
            if ( DBData2!== null){
                for (var i = 0; i < DBData2.length; i++) {
                    temp_list.push(DBData2[i].dataValues.wa_property_name)
                }
                temp_obj[wa_account_name] = temp_list
                temp_list = []
                console.log(temp_obj)          
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(temp_obj)   
    res.json({ success: true, account_property_list: temp_obj }); return;
})
```